# High-order functions in Haskell - "No instances for..."

Tags: haskell

map2 takes two lists, ls1 and ls2 and a function F, and returns a list that is the same length as the shortest of ls1 and ls2, and in which the ith element is the result of applying F to the ith elements of ls1 and ls2 (in that order)

```
module Map2 where

map2 lst1 lst2 f = map2_iter lst1 lst2 f len 0 []
    where len = (min (length lst1), (length lst2))
map2_iter (x:lst1) (y:lst2) f len i acc = if (i == len)
                      then acc
                      else let res = (f x y) in
                      map2_iter (lst1) (lst2) (f) (len) (i+1) ((res):acc)
map2_iter [] [] f len i acc = []
```

**I got the following error**

```
Map2.hs:3:20:
No instances for (Eq (Int -> Int), Num (Int -> Int, Int))
  arising from a use of `map2_iter'
Possible fix:
  add instance declarations for
  (Eq (Int -> Int), Num (Int -> Int, Int))
In the expression: map2_iter lst1 lst2 f len 0 []
In an equation for `map2':
    map2 lst1 lst2 f
      = map2_iter lst1 lst2 f len 0 []
      where
          len = (min (length lst1), (length lst2))
```

I'm not really sure what this error means. Can anyone provide any help?

Also, this is not hw but rather test prepation.

Comment: Shoud you get this to work you'll notice that the result comes out in reverse. Unlike in `zipWith` which really does what you think your function does. But before you get this to work, you'll also suffer a pattern match error as soon as you use lists of different length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you can't compare `Int -> Int` functions for equality and that `(Int -> Int, Int)` tuples aren't numbers. Why is it telling you this? Because `len` in your code is an `(Int -> Int, Int)` tuple and you're trying to both compare it for equality and treat it as a number.

So how did `len` end up being a number? `(,)` is used to create tuples in Haskell. Writing `(x,y)` creates a tuple whose first element is `x` and whose second element is `y`. So `(min (length lst1), (length lst2))` creates a tuple whose first element is `min (length lst1)` and whose second element is `length lst2`. So you end up with a tuple that contains a function (because `min (length lst1)` evaluates to a function) and a number.

PS: I should also point out that writing this function tail-recursively like you did is not a good idea. The way you wrote it, you won't be able to access the first element of the result until the entire result is generated (also the resulting list will have the wrong order). Writing it in the more "naive" non-tail-recursive way would be lazier and thus perform better. It would also be simpler.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Could you provide a "naive" non-tail-recursive way of writing this function?

Comment: Look at the zipWith function.